# High Load Event Gateways For ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

How good are event gateways at handling high loads of volume? For example 2k-20k requests per second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On one server? Not bloody likely, regardless of your gateway's actual work.

There isn't enough detail to answer the question, but the only true way to tell is with testing using similar hardware.